# Plotting simple points

Tags: c, plot, terminal, points

I came here to find out how to plot simple points in C given this simple code.
I only want to construct plot_points method.
Although I didn't take the full code, what the code wants to do is

1. Getting the number n
2. Fix n points randomly
3. Print points in terminal (looks like graph)

and I missed third step after a long day of searching..

Thanks for reading

```c
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} point;

srand( time(NULL));
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    x = rand() % RANGE + 1;
    y = rand() % RANGE + 1;

    p[j].x = x;
    p[j].y = y;
}

void print_points( point *p, int n)
{
}
```

Comment: One way to achieve this is rendering the complete graph in a 2D array and printing the 2D array.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "print points in terminal". Would you be happy with ascii art of "x" and " "? That would proably limit `RANGE` to something below 50.

Comment: @Yunnosch we can render any point in the limited plane we have by normalizing the points to our required plane

Comment: @Yunnosch I elaborated a little. I meant to print in picture

Answer (score 1):

We can render a graph on a 2D array and flush the array to screen at the end. Here is the simplest implementation of the graph plotted in the terminal. This assumes the point.x and point.y fall between 0 and MAXWIDTH and MAXHEIGHT. We can extend this idea to huge points by scaling them to our limited plane but there is a precision tradeoff.

EDIT: I have added the scaling code as well.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXWIDTH    30
#define MAXHEIGHT   30

#define MAXX        100
#define MAXY        100

#define NPTS 3

int main() {
    /* our limited plane */
    char G[MAXHEIGHT][MAXWIDTH];

    /* points to be plotted */
    int pts[NPTS][2] = {
        {20,90},
        {94,39},
        {15, 5}
    };

    /* clean up the plane */
    for(int i=0; i<MAXHEIGHT; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<MAXWIDTH; j++)
            G[i][j]=' ';

    /* find out the scaling factor */
    double scalex=(double)MAXWIDTH/MAXX;
    double scaley=(double)MAXHEIGHT/MAXY;

    /* render the points on plane here, scaling must be applied here */
    for(int i=0; i<NPTS; i++) {
        G[(int)(pts[i][1] * scaley)][(int)(pts[i][0] * scalex)] = '*';
    }

    /* render to screen */
    for(int i=0; i<MAXHEIGHT; i++) {
        printf("\n   +");
        for(int j=0; j<MAXWIDTH; j++) {
            putchar(G[i][j]);
        }
    }

    /* print the bottom line */
    printf("\n     ");
    for(int i=0; i<MAXWIDTH; i++)
        putchar('|');
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Output (you may want to add more cosmetic stuff if you want):

```
   +                              
   +    *                         
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                            * 
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +                              
   +      *                       
   +                              
   +                              
     ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

If you want, you can generate graphs in HTML by writing SVG to a file. I have small implementation done here https://github.com/mmpataki/mchartjs/tree/master/cport

Comment: For me, your concept of normalisation needs more explanation, mabye with examples with and without.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant scaling. For eg (20,40) in a plane of size 100x100 can be rendered as (10,20) in 50x50 plane.